# Is my fast broken?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

just wanted to ask that a min before athan, I drank water and my mouth and you know when your mouth is moist after water, I swallowed the water but after that my mouth was moist and the Athan started and I just swallowed my saliva and the moist in my mouth. Does that count as me breaking my fast?

Answer (score 1):

No, your fast did not break. Your action of drinking happened before Athaan. The moisture just happened to be there afterwards. Also, you could eat after the athaan as the Siyaam starts a bit before dawn, and the athaan is still before that time. Anyway, any unintentional eating drinking is forgiven, even if you had it in the middle of the Siyaam.